# Given the curvature and torsion, find the curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I need some help on the following problem:

> Given that a curve $\mathbf r:I\to \Bbb R ^3$ has constant curvature $k(s)=k$, for all $s$, and constant torsion $\tau(s)=\tau$, for all $s$. Find the curve $\mathbf r$.

I only know that, according to the fundamental theorem, this curve exists and is unique. But, how practically find the parametric equation of the curve?

Thanks.

Comment: One can prove that a curve has constant curvature, $\kappa\neq0$ and constant torsion, $\tau$, iff the curve is a helix; of course if $\kappa = 0$, then talking about torsion doesn't make sense. Surely this helps.

Comment: What happens if we change the function ? For example lets take $k=h(t) $ and $t=g(t)$ where $h,g$ are continuous functions then how we find that unique curve, is there an algorithm, or we can't find it.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: set $r=\kappa/(\kappa^2+\tau^2)$, $h=\tau/(\kappa^2+\tau^2)$. Let $s$ be the arc-length function of $\mathbf r$ with $s(t_0)=0$ and define $\phi(t)=s(t)/\sqrt{r^2+h^2}$.  We want to construct an orthonormal basis ($a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$) and a point $p_0$ such that 
$$\mathbf r(t)=p_0+r\bigl(\cos(t)a_1+\sin(t)a_2\bigr)+hta_3.$$

First show -- per differentiating twice -- that for $\tilde c=\mathbf r+rN$ there's a point $p_0$ and a vector $v\neq0$ such that $\tilde c(t)=p_0+s(t)\cdot v$. Now chose a suitable orthogonal basis $(a_1,a_2)$ for the orthogonal complement of $\boldsymbol Rv$ such that $\langle -N(t),a_1\rangle=\cos(\phi(t))$ and $\langle -N(t),a_2\rangle=\sin(\phi(t))$.

Comment: How did you come up with that $r = ...$ ?

Comment: Simply because with that definition of $r$ all will work well.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but I didn't ask who do you choose $r$ in that way; I asked **how** did you **come up** with that.

Comment: If torsion and curvature are constant, the curve should be a helix. And a helix satisfies these equation.

Answer (score 0):

To find the arc-parameterization $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}(s)$ you must resolve

$$\frac{\mathbf{r}'\cdot \mathbf{r}''\times \mathbf{r}'''}{\|\mathbf{r}''^2\|}=\tau,$$
$$\|\mathbf{r}'(s)\|=1,$$
$$\|\mathbf{r}''(s)\|=k,$$

for some injective differential map $\mathbf{r}:I\hookrightarrow{\Bbb{R}}^3$ over some open interval $I$.

Comment: I have a question about the first equation. The LHS is a vector, but the RHS is a scalar? Indeed, I do have the last two equations, but solving them is a trouble for me. Do you have any hints on solving them?

Comment: you was right, now i did correct.

Comment: to solve them you gotta begin to unfold $\mathbf{r}(s)=(x(s),y(s),z(s))$ then $\mathbf{r}'=(x',y',z')$, $\mathbf{r}''=(x'',y'',z'')$... etc

Answer (score 0):

Central line u = 0 of helicoid surface $ (u \cos t, u \sin t , c t) $ treated as a stand alone space curve has zero curvature and constant torsion.